# When I render a string with a newline, ejs throws a "TypeError: Cannot create property '_locals' on string" error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used ExpressJS to pass a string variable containing "\n" in the form of `res.render('index', string)`, and in ejs output it in the form of `<%= string %>`.

```
// string : abc\nabc\n
```

However, the string variable is printed in HTML, but the error text is printed on the page with "TypeError: Cannot create property '_locals' on string".

How can I output a string variable I have normally in ejs?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `res.render('index', { string })` (or more verbosely `res.render('index', { string: string })`)?

Comment: @phil If passed as an object, the "\n" contained in the string is not rendered on the html.

Comment: Does '\n' in your string indicate a new line?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia Yes.

Comment: Newlines mean nothing in HTML unless you render it in a `<pre>` or translate them to `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a new line escape character '\' as shown below:

```
string : abc\\nabc\\n
```